# Using \dots inside \bm causes an error

Tags: math-mode, errors, symbols, bold, bm

I can't figure out why this error keeps happening. I simply use \dots inside \bm as is shown in the following image:

[image]

The equation of the middle reads:

> $$\bm{d\omega^i\wedge\omega^1\wedge\dots\wedge\omega^{n-k}=0}$$

Here are my packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\rel@kern[1]{\kern#1\dimexpr\macc@kerna}
\newcommand*\widebar[1]{%
\begingroup
\def\mathaccent##1##2{%
    \rel@kern{0.8}%
    \overline{\rel@kern{-0.8}\macc@nucleus\rel@kern{0.2}}%
    \rel@kern{-0.2}%
}%
\macc@depth\@ne
\let\math@bgroup\@empty \let\math@egroup\macc@set@skewchar
\mathsurround\z@ \frozen@everymath{\mathgroup\macc@group\relax}%
\macc@set@skewchar\relax
\let\mathaccentV\macc@nested@a
\macc@nested@a\relax111{#1}%
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newlength\bshft
\bshft=.18pt\relax
\def\fakebold#1{\ThisStyle{\ooalign{$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
        \kern-\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$\cr%
        \kern\bshft$\SavedStyle#1$}}}

\usepackage{tikz} % Para pictures
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows} %decoracion en tikz
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{optics}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\newcommand{\longsquiggly}{\xymatrix{{}\ar@{~>}[r]&{}}}

\renewenvironment{proof}%
{\noindent{\em Demostración. }\nopagebreak}%
{\hfill\linebreak[2]\hspace*{\fill}$\Box$\\[6pt]}
```

Comment: I get the following message from the compiler: Font shape `U/stmry/b/n' undefined(Font) using `U/stmry/m/n' instead

Comment: please make a small and complete example. Not one which loads lots of large unrelated packages.

Comment: _nothing_ is simple in `\bm`. please make a more reasonable example: I don't want to have to trace `tikz-cd` here for example.

Comment: @Akerbeltz that message is just telling you stmry fonts are not available in bold but that is unrelated to the question I would assume. You should be able to make an example with just standard fonts

Comment: also please show a small but complete document your actual bm example is an image that makes it hard to debug,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more reasonble test document would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[\bm{X\dots Y}\]

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\mdots@@ ->\gdef \thedots@ 
                           {\dotso@ }\ifx \@let@token \boldsymbol \gdef \the...
l.8 \[\bm{X\dots Y}
                   \]
?
```

As the package documents, some constructs require protecting in a brace group, so

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[\bm{{X\dots Y}}\]

\end{document}
```

Or as it is the entire expression it is *much* more efficient to not use `bm` at all:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\boldmath
\[X\dots Y\]

\end{document}
```